# How to provide module definition when @types/x does not exist

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

With a webpack build I have:

```
import { setLanguage } from 'redux-polyglot';
```

but it says:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I tried using:

```
declare module 'redux-polyglot';
```

but nothing changed, still get the error. How do I define the module for myself?
Here is the error I get:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Just use:

```
    const reduxPolyglot = require('redux-polyglot');
```

instead of

```
   import * as reduxPolyglot from 'redux-polyglot'
```

2. the more ideal way:

You must put this in *its own file*:

```
declare module 'redux-polyglot' {
  export const polyglotReducer: any
}
```

do not put anything else in the file. As long as this file is in the `include` property array in tsconfig.json, you will be good to go.